# Limited read/write access in C++ class

Tags: c++, class

I'm refreshing my basics of C++. I'm trying to implement a simple project with a Student and a Teacher class (possibly subclasses of some base class). The teacher object will have a list of grades and the student object will have a list of reports. The teacher object should have read access to the reports and write access to the grades. The other way round for the student object. But also the information should not be public.

Somehow I can't figure out how to implement this simple example using either subclass or friend structure. I'm not sure if I'm being stupid or it really is not possible this way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please show your code. YOu know the difficulties, others might not see them, so you need to tell what they are if you need help to overcome them

Comment: I'm interested in which scripting language has this ability.

Comment: Every class in C++ has read/write access to itself. So the only requirement here seems to be to give 'the world' read only access to both lists. That seems straightforward to me. Neither friendship or subclassing is necessary (and subclassing has nothing at all to do with access anyway). It might help to show some of your attempts

Comment: fwiw, I dont think the phrase "I am coming back to c++ after some time.." conveys the meaning you actually intended. In any case it isnt relevant for the question

Comment: @john Yes, but I don't want the world to see, I just want the student/teacher to be able to see. Otherwise, I could just make it public altogether. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Sarah As a general principle I don't think it matters to give the world read only access to objects. What harm can it do? But if that's what you want then you could use friendship, but that's a blunt instrument, each class will have total access to the other class. So I'm not sure it is possible to achieve precisely what you want. You should rethink your goals IMHO.

Comment: i second john. A teacher should not be able to see a studends private reports. Consider this two very different situations in real life: A student submits their report to the teacher by mail. vs The teacher breaks into the students house, opens their desk and reads their report. Imho `friend` has a terrible name, it sounds much too friendly for what it actually does

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain words. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: C++ access modifiers are just suggestions, like guard rails. The reason the student can't modify their report card is that you didn't write any code for students to modify report cards - the word `private:` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user253751 or the report card class prevent student from modifying it.

Comment: @appleapple or you didn't write code to make students modify it!

Comment: @user253751 yes, well, but that's the point of access modifier.

Comment: Essentially, you are looking at a database and determining each User's accessibility rights.  You may want to create a separate object to represent the database.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, so how would you then determine the rights of the user, by checking for the type of the asking object?

Comment: One method is to have a table: <role, data1_rights, data2_rights>.  Maybe put it into a Singleton.  The role could be string.  There are many other methods, just play with the objects / entities (draw relational diagrams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a key class

```cpp
class TeacherKey{
    TeacherKey(){};
    friend class Teacher; // only teacher can get the key
};

class Student{ // or `ReportCard` class 
public:
    void SetGrade(TeacherKey);
    int GetReport(TeacherKey);
};

class Teacher{
    void foo(){
        Student s;
        s.SetGrade({}); // work
    }
};

void foo(){
    Student s;
    s.SetGrade({}); // fail
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to avoid to give `Teacher` full access to `Student` internals. But maybe add a parameter to the _setter_ otherwise it's quite useless :D

Comment: Thanks this is more along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

One can only guess what problem you encountered.

Making the classes friends just works to grant them mutual access to their private bits:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    friend struct B;
    void doSomething(const B& b);
    private:
        int x = 42;
};

struct B {
    friend A;
    void doSomething(const A& a);
    private:
        int y = 42;
};

void A::doSomething(const B& b) { std::cout << b.y; }
void B::doSomething(const A& a) { std::cout << a.x; }

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.doSomething(b);
    b.doSomething(a);
}
```